# Counter example to disprove the statement"if the series of sums of each two adjacent terms converges, then the whole series converges"

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

It is well known that if 
\begin{equation}
S_{1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} F_{n}
\end{equation}
converges, then
\begin{equation}
S_{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} F_{2n-1}+F_{2n}
\end{equation}
converges

But I know that given that $S2$ converges then $S1$ may diverges.

Why is that true? Could someone give me a counterexample to let me see the fact? Or could someone give me a hint to build up such an counterexample? Many thanks!

Comment: Say $S_1=\sum (-1)^n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $F_n=(-1)^n$.  Then we have

$$S_2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{2n-1}+(-1)^{2n}=0+0+0+\dots0=0$$

On the other hand,

$$S_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n=-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+\dots$$

which doesn't converge to anything.