# The total sequence converges implies the sequence of sum of each 2 adjacent terms convergent

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given that
\begin{equation}
S_{1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} F_{n}
\end{equation}
converges.

How to prove that S2 also converges and it converges to the same value as S1 does.

\begin{equation}
S_{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (F_{2n-1}+F_{2n})
\end{equation}

I am thinking maybe we should prove the statement:"Convergent series implies convergent sequence". But does it actually hold?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counter example to disprove the statement"if the series of sums of each two adjacent terms converges, then the whole series converges"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1939477/counter-example-to-disprove-the-statementif-the-series-of-sums-of-each-two-adja)

Comment: @Simple Art No,I didn't. Latter I regarded that I was not even able to prove the original correct statement. So I asked to prove it. There is another question to disprove the converse.

Comment: Oh, my bad.  Well then, cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $a_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}F_n$ be the $N$th partial sum of the first series. Then the sequence $\{a_N\}$ converges, with $\lim_{N\to\infty}a_N=S_1$.

The $N$th partial sum of the second series is then
$$ b_N=\sum_{n=1}^N(F_{2n-1}+F_{2n})=F_1+F_2+\dots+F_{2N-1}+F_{2N}=a_{2N} $$

In other words, the partial sums of the second series are a subsequence of the partial sums of the first series. But if a sequence converges, then every subsequence converges to the same limit, hence $\lim_{N\to\infty}b_N=S_1$ as well. This shows that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(F_{2n-1}+F_{2n})=S_1$.